# Ansible How to copy the content to file with user input

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am just trying to write ansible-playbook where I have to give an input to the file content.

For Example

```
Enter the File Lists
7124 /var/www/A.txt
7125 /var/www/B.txt
```

This has to update on file `/tmp/filelist.txt` as a content.

When I do the cat

```
cat /tmp/filelist.txt
7124 /var/www/A.txt
7125 /var/www/B.txt
```

I tried using copy content, but it could not able to achieve.

Comment: Please provide the code snippets that you've tried.

Comment: If you solved your own problem please post it as an answer. SO will let you mark your own answer as accepted in 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose to use copy instead of lineinfile

```
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
    - copy: 
        dest: /tmp/A.txt
        content: |
          7124 /var/www/A.txt
          7125 /var/www/B.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I able to perform by this method

```
- hosts: localhost 
  connection: localhost
  tasks:
  - lineinfile: dest=/tmp/A.txt create=yes
                 line="{{item}}"
    with_items:
      - 7124 /var/www/A.txt
      - 7125 /var/www/B.txt
```